# Background and foreground colors for brace highlighting

Tags: aptana

Current functionality just outlines the matching brace which is hard to see.  How would I change the foreground and background colors as well so the matching brace appears over a solid block?

Aptana Studio 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that Aptana inherits from Eclipse, which is hard-coded to draw a rectangle around the matching pair character. So, unfortunately, this is not something you can change right now.

For tag pair matches in HTML/XML (the tag open/close pair, not the less than/greater than), you can modify how it's displayed in *Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations*.