# How Do I Change Highlight for Javascript Brace/Bracket Matching in Aptana 3 Plugin to Eclipse 3?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, aptana

In Aptana 3 Plugin to Eclipse 3 Javascript editor the matching brace/bracket is NOT highlighted very clearly.  In fact the beginning brace is NOT highlighted at all and the ending brace is indicated ONLY by a thin rectangle around the brace.

I would like to highlight both the beginning and ending brace with a background color that will stand out, like yellow, bright blue, or bright green.

I have been all over the Preferences, documents, and google, but I cannot find out how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873115/background-and-foreground-colors-for-brace-highlighting) says that it's a feature inherited from eclipse so there is currently no way to change it.

The only thing I could find is to change the 'Caret' color under Aptana Studio -> Themes and that will change the color of the Caret, along with the color of the little rectangle which makes it s a little bit easier to see.